# why can I only define 6 custom CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Using Q GIS 1.8.0 - I am trying to create several custom CRS definitions for the purpose of rectifying several split areas of a census shapefile.
In the "Custom Coordinate Reference System Definition" window I seem to be limited to creating no more than 6 custom CRS. If I advance the arrows to 6 of 6 and enter a new definition it overwrites USER 100006: CRS. This is repeated on any of the other CRS definitions (1 of 6, USER 100000, etc...).
Can I only create 6???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click on the yellow star to enter a new custom CRS. And don't forget to save by clicking on the diskette symbol afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized this was working - It does not actually add another number (i.e. 7 of 7) until after you click save using the diskette